# How to upload an XML file to wishlist in bricklink

Tags: bricklink

I am trying to upload an XML file with my brick wishlist to BrickLink. 
However, even if I follow the [instructions on the webpage](https://www.bricklink.com/help.asp?helpID=207), it never seems to find the product in the catalogue. If I manually use the search bar to search it in the catalogue however, it will always find it.

I have no idea what is wrong.

The help says:

```
<INVENTORY>
    <ITEM>
        <ITEMTYPE>P</ITEMTYPE>
        <ITEMID>3622</ITEMID> 
        <COLOR>11</COLOR> 
    </ITEM>
</INVENTORY>
```

If I change that to:

```
<INVENTORY>
    <ITEM>
        <ITEMTYPE>P</ITEMTYPE>
        <ITEMID>3062</ITEMID> 
        <COLOR>23</COLOR> 
    </ITEM>
</INVENTORY>
```

It doesn't work. However it does exist: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3062b&ccName=306223

and that with the 6 Digit IDs. What about the other ID types, the ones that can not be broken into colour/ID? e.g.: 4211425

How can I upload my list to Bricklink?

Comment: I found this question, wanting to know how to upload a CSV file to a BrickLink Wanted List.  Your comment on uploading XML was a valuable lead.  You might want to add the referenced BrickLink page that tells about XML uploads:  www.bricklink.com/help.asp?helpID=207.  I add it here to help others.  For me, I needed to convert my CSV to XML, then it uploaded fine (less the quarks mentioned here).

Comment: @Thomas the webpage is massively changed since I asked this question, so I believe the content you link to is new! feel free to add it to the question, or add an answer with the information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bricklink is correct - 3062 does not exist. Your link shows 3062b, which DOES exist (Don't ask me why the base number does not exist though :) ). So if you change your XML to

```
    <INVENTORY>
        <ITEM>
            <ITEMTYPE>P</ITEMTYPE>
            <ITEMID>3062b</ITEMID> 
            <COLOR>23</COLOR> 
        </ITEM> 
    </INVENTORY>
```

It should load.

I do not know the answer to the second part of your question: 4211425 translates to ITEMID 3460 in color White, and the Catalog knows this, but the wanted list does not :(.

Comment: I see, but the catalogue translates 3062 properly when searched manually. Again, I am losing the point if I need to manually search for everything!

Comment: Yes - totally annoying. At this point I don't know either how you can go from your ID numbers to the ones used in Bricklink without first looking them up and translating them. And I do not understand why Bricklink allows you to search for a 7-digit ID, but cannot upload it in the Wanted List functionality. Sharing your frustration here, but perhaps someone else on this forum can answer the question for you. A quick google search showed many ways to upload 4/5-digit IDs, but nothing on the long IDs you have.